# Error in UseMethod("group_by") for cluster analysis in R

Tags: r, error-handling, group-by, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

I have tried running the following code for a cluster analysis (the data frame has 104 rows of data)

```
#Explore mean values of variables in clusters
segments <- df_final %>%
  group_by(cluster) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(newCasesByPublishDate, newOnsDeathsByRegistrationDate, IMD19, RUC11),
               list(M = mean))
segments
```

After I've run the code I have the following error message

```
Error in UseMethod("group_by") : 
  no applicable method for 'group_by' applied to an object of class "c('matrix', 'array', 'list')"
```

I would be very grateful for any suggestions, advice, help, etc!

Thanks!

Comment: The error message suggests that your dataset `df_final` isn't a dataframe but a matrix instead. Try with converting to a dataframe. Anyway it would be easier to help you if you share a snippet of your data using `dput()`

Comment: Here's a snippet of the data I'm using `structure(list(newCasesByPublishDate = c(269, 269, 269, 269, 269, 269, 269, 269, 269, 269), newOnsDeathsByRegistrationDate = c(35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35), IMD19 = c(28635, 5389, 27368, 27114, 8007, 16201, 13570, 28047, 1662, 6031), RUC11 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2))`